# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "после"?

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги, запятые

Это была настоящая буря после тёплых дней января, когда хорошо ещё, если снега сантиметр-два выпадет.

Comment: Никак не пойму "когда хорошо ещё, если снега сантиметр-два выпадет" — это о чем? Автор хочет сказать, что январь обычно такой теплый, что мало снега выпадет?

Answer (score 2):

Оснований для запятой нет, поскольку здесь обстоятельство времени не относится к таким, которые принято отделять:

a) к уточняющим (здесь нет сужения более широкого понятия);

б) к выраженным деепричастным оборотом.

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_177

В качестве дополнительного ориентира здесь можно  усмотреть тесную смысловую связь обстоятельства с существительным "буря" (ср. "пир во время чумы"), которая делает неестественной какую-либо попытку его отделения. Нет здесь и явного противопоставления, которое могло бы выражаться с использованием тире, например:

> Это была настоящая буря - да ещё после тёплых дней января!

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна: **Это была настоящая буря после тёплых дней январЯ, когда хорошо ещё, если снега сантиметр-два выпадет.**

**Это тема "лишних запятых",** а вот откуда они берутся?

В распространенном предложении могут присутствовать **произносительные паузы между группами слов**, которые запятой не должны обозначаться, но иногда ошибочно обозначаются.

Возьмем простое предложение:  **Это была настоящая бУря // после тёплых дней январЯ.**

Здесь пауза делается на переломе интонации **между двумя фразами** (между темой и ремой), но запятой она тоже по правилам не обозначается.  Структура предложения  такова: предикативная основа - обстоятельство.

Это же предложение в составе сложного предложения является у**же одной фразой (с одним ударением),** а пауза между темой и ремой становится произносительной. Но она по-прежнему провоцирует пользователей на постановку запятой, **не имеющей грамматического обоснования.**

Answer (score 1):

*Это была настоящая буря - после тёплых дней января, когда хорошо ещё, если снега сантиметр-два выпадет.*

В этом предложении нужно поставить интонационное (экспрессивное) тире на месте пропущенного слова, ср.:*Это была настоящая буря, буря после тёплых дней января, когда хорошо ещё, если снега сантиметр-два выпадет.* Или: *Это была настоящая буря, разыгравшаяся после тёплых дней января, когда хорошо ещё, если снега сантиметр-два выпадет.*

Смысл предложения сводится к тому, что буря была неожиданной после тёплых дней. Тире помогает передать этот смысл.

Comment: Два слова в поддержку именно такого ответа.  При отсутствии тире  получается, что "настоящая" относится ко всей группе слов "буря после тёплых дней января", а это неверно ("настоящая" относится только к "буря").

Comment: Да, именно так. Вы очень хорошо всё понимаете. Благодарю Вас.